# Extract tooltip text by selenium using Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Can someone help to extract tooltip text from the following website with the help of selenium or is there any other method that we can perform using python

https://opennem.org.au/facility/au/NEM/CLOVER/?range=3d&interval=30m

I need this tooltip text

[image]

Using selenium, I could reach only the span element
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains` to hover.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
# set chromodriver.exe path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\chromedriver\\chromedriver108.exe')
driver.maximize_window()
# launch URL
driver.get("https://opennem.org.au/facility/au/NEM/CLOVER/?range=3d&interval=30m")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
# object of ActionChains
a = ActionChains(driver)
# identify table
td = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//td[@class='unit-name has-tooltip']")
# hover over table
a.move_to_element(td).perform()
# identify tooltip
tt = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='tooltip-inner']")
# print tooltip text
print(tt.text)
# close browser
driver.close()
```

To get whole table's tooltip text

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
# js code to remove tooltip text div
jscode = "return document.getElementsByClassName('tooltip-inner')[0].remove();"
# set chromodriver.exe path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\chromedriver\\chromedriver108.exe')
# maximize window
driver.maximize_window()
# object of WebDriverWait
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10)
# object of ActionChains
action = ActionChains(driver)
# launch URL
driver.get("https://opennem.org.au/facility/au/NEM/CLOVER/?range=3d&interval=30m")
# tooltip texts
ttexts = []
# identify table
td = wait.until(lambda d: d.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//td[@class='unit-name has-tooltip']"))
# iterate trough rows
for i in td:
    # hover over table row
    action.move_to_element(i).perform()
    # here we will force
    while True:
        # identify element
        tt = wait.until(lambda d: d.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='tooltip-inner']"))
        # get text
        text = tt.text
        # if text is not null
        if text:
            # append text to list
            ttexts.append(text)
            # remove div to ensure there is no left another one
            driver.execute_script(jscode)
            break

for text in ttexts:
    # print tooltip text
    print("Tooltip text ->", text)

# close browser
driver.close()
```

Comment: Hi @muhammadyusuf, Thank you it's working fine but it's just giving me the table's first element hover tooltip text. What do I need to do in order to get the whole table's tooltip text?